# How to configure CSW and metadata in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, metadata, geonetwork, csw, inspire

I am setting up a geodata service. The plan is to write metadata in GeoServer and then publish services and metadata with Geonetwork. I have set up the GeoServer CSW and metadata functions, and get proper responses from GetCapabilities and GetRecords requests.
But cannot harvest the GeoServer CSW with Geonetwork.
(I have a couple of other csw harvesters that work so I know the setup I think)
I have concluded that the error lies in the mapping of data fields. I have put in and checked all the suggested mapping files.

The harvester fails with this error (redacted)

```
- Started harvesting from node : Giskraft csw (CswHarvester)
 - Unable to process record from csw (Giskraft csw)
 - Record failed: misc:sockenstad. Error is: Invalid ISO date: Unknown
 - Invalid ISO date: Unknown
 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ISO date: Unknown
```

Checking a direct GS CSW response for the same record I see

```
<gmd:dateStamp>
<gco:Date xsi:nil="false">Unknown</gco:Date>
</gmd:dateStamp>
```

None of the mapping files has any "dateStamp" item, so I am not sure what is requested here? The layer has a publication date set in metadata but it is not displayed. Instead it displays Unknown which appears like above in the harvester error log.
If I put in a random datetime instead of 'Unknown', the harvester works. But that is of course completely pointless. I would like the datestamp to be the publishing date of the service.

I might add that I can import metadata records the other way, to GeoServer CSW from Geonetwork. I want to work the other way, though.

This may very well be a Geonetwork problem, but I am starting here.

Comment: Documentation https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/metadata/configuration.html shows `key: metadata-datestamp` in the UI attributes and I think that it is set with the input box just after metadata-identifier. Have you defined the date there?

Comment: Of course. I have three dates, creation date, publishing date and revision date. None of these appear in the csw record which is harvested for metadata.

Comment: Geonetwork should be able to harvest records even if they are invalid, so missing values shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: But don't you think that those three dates are not the one that you are missing? They seem to appear later as `data-identification-date`.

Comment: My guess is that the name of the datefield in the metdata UI configuration does not match the name in the MD_Metdata.properties files. If you followed the examples the MD_Metadata.properties files has _metadata.date_, but the Metadata UI configuration has _key: metdata-datestamp_. For testing purposes you can change any field in MD_Metadata.properties to contain "metdata", then you will see all available keys in the metadata dictionary. Eg. set identificationInfo.AbstractMD_Identification.abstract.CharacterString="metadata"

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. That is exactly my analysis, and I have been perusing the code to find a way to extract the syntax for available keys. However, the result is most disappointing. The metadata string I get from your tip is just this:
<gco:CharacterString>{kml.regionateFeatureLimit=10, cacheAgeMax=3600, cachingEnabled=true, indexingEnabled=false, dirName=DS_poi_poi}</gco:CharacterString>
No dates, no useful metadata at all. What is wrong here?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't used the metadata extension myself. Just using the csw-iso extension and tried to extract everyting useful already present i Geoserver. But according to the INSPIRE example https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/metadata/index.html the custom metadata properties are available as metadata.custom.*. Even if that works, it would be nice to have an automatically updated datestamp.